# Netty - second request to the same connection

Tags: java, netty

When I send second request, handler does not process response, here is code:

```
public class Test extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
    protected boolean close = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        String url = "http://example.com";
        ChannelFactory channelFactory  = new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        final URI uri = new URI(url);
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("codec", new HttpClientCodec());
        pipeline.addLast("inflater", new HttpContentDecompressor());
        pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(1048576));
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new Test());
        Channel channel = channelFactory.newChannel(pipeline);
        InetSocketAddress inetAddress = new InetSocketAddress(uri.getHost(), 80);
        channel.connect(inetAddress).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("connected");
                Channel channel = future.getChannel();
                if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                    future.getCause().printStackTrace();
                } else {
                    HttpRequest request = new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, uri.toASCIIString());
                    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.HOST, uri.getHost());
                    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.CLOSE);
                    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.ACCEPT_ENCODING, HttpHeaders.Values.GZIP);
                    channel.write(request);
                    System.out.println("sent first request");
                }

            }
        });
    }



      @Override
      public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
              System.out.println("done");
              if (!close) { 
                  URI uri = new URI("http://example.com");
                  HttpRequest request = new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, uri.toASCIIString());
                  request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.HOST, uri.getHost());
                  request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.CLOSE);
                  request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.ACCEPT_ENCODING, HttpHeaders.Values.GZIP);
                  e.getChannel().write(request).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                      public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture arg0) throws Exception {
                          System.out.println("sent second request");
                      }
                  });
                  close = true;
              } else {
                  ctx.getChannel().close();
                  System.out.println("closing");
              }
      }


}
```

In output I see only:

```
connected
sent first request
done
sent second request
```

Why there is no second "done"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You instruct the server to close the connection, so that is probably what's happening (add a channelClosed() method to check). This is in fact fortunate, otherwise you would've created an infinite loop (until the ops at example.com blacklists you as a DOS attack ;-) ).

Comment: I don't want to close connection(such as doing browsers), this is just example, and to do a dos attack i think i must send more then few requests in second.

Comment: Added close channel after second request

Comment: But you add the header `Connection: close` to your request. THat will cause either your stack or the server to close the connection after the first request.

Comment: Thx, that was a problem, now it's ok, changed to KEEP_ALIVE